# WinInet connecting to java

Tags: java, apache, http, delphi, wininet

I'm working on some converting Delphi code to Java.

In Delphi they have used winInet Microsoft API to create a connection to a specified URL and updates a column while passing a URL and does some upload operation (similar to mail sending) .

How do I connect with winInet in Java and achieve all the operations done in Delphi?

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: Java has networking libraries. Use them.

Comment: Search the web for "java http client library"